# How to Query Sharepoint List Data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Does anyone know how to  fetch Sharepoint List data using sql query based on the particular sharepoint user.

Comment: In which language? Do you mean a SQL query to the SQL Server directly??? Or do you mean to query a Sharepoint List with a SQL-syntax from JavaScript? For this last option (SQL-syntax with JavaScript), look at http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.list.html#.get

Answer (score 5):

You <s>cannot use</s> **should not really be using** SQL to get data from SharePoint list. Most common way of doing this is custom solution where you can use CAML (SPQuery) to retrieve data for list items (created by the user for example) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.aspx or else you can expose the SharePoint services to get the same results http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint/jj164060.aspx.

Comment: To extend Velin's answer, you have to consider the SharePoint as blackboxes. Not only the schema is very weird (fitting a document database in a relational database is not very natural nor simple), but Microsoft is saying that the schema is not fixed and may change eventually with new releases.

Comment: That's great except CAML (SPQuery) is a pretty pitiful excuse for a query language unless you want a simple select statement with no aggregation, distinct, or TOP features.

Comment: There are many scenarios where you may have to do this or it is required for whatever reason you have not answered the question, which was how to do it in SQL Server using SQL Statements I would vote you down but I don't have enough points.

Comment: Access is doing it with 'add external data -> online services -> sharepoint' and makes a 'table'. Anyhow what would be an alternative to export from sharepoint list to a sql table?

Answer (score 5):

As long as it is SharePoint 2010 it is still relatively easy to pull from SQL as long as you have the list id GUID

See [here](http://speverything.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/how-to-pull-sharepoint-list-data-from-sql-server/)

```
    SELECT
    ud.tp_ID
    , ud.tp_ListId
    , ud.tp_Author
    , ud.nvarchar1
    , ud.nvarchar2
    , ud.nvarchar3
    , ud.nvarchar4
    , ud.nvarchar5
    , ud.nvarchar6
    , ud.nvarchar7
    , ud.nvarchar8
    , ud.nvarchar9
    , ud.nvarchar10
    , ud.nvarchar11
    , ud.nvarchar12
    , ud.*
    FROM dbo.UserData ud
    WHERE (ud.tp_ListId =  '[{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}')
```

Comment: Note you don't need the dbo.Lists join here (or else you want to do l.* in the end?)

Comment: Quite correct, you don't need the Lists table in this query, I have made the changes

Comment: How about when data is overflowed and there are wrapped rows?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for my case - display SP list

```
select l.tp_title
, n1.title.value('(text())[1]', 'nvarchar(32)') as Title
, n2.[status].value('(text())[1]', 'nvarchar(32)') as [Status]
, n3.[priority].value('(text())[1]', 'nvarchar(32)') as [Priority]
from Lists l
join UserData u on u.tp_ListId = l.tp_ID
cross apply tp_ColumnSet.nodes('/nvarchar1') AS n1(title)
cross apply tp_ColumnSet.nodes('/nvarchar3') AS n2([status])
cross apply tp_ColumnSet.nodes('/nvarchar4') AS n3([priority])
where l.tp_title = 'LIST NAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your SP list will need a field that captures the users account info. Using SQL Report Builder with a SharePoint list data connection, set a parameter on your report for `@User`. Set this as a hidden parameter. Set the default value of this parameter to `=Right(User!UserID,8)`: this will give you the last 8 characters of the Users Account info which you can then filter your dataset on (your account info may be more or less than 8 so build based on your settings). You will need to set a filter on the dataset or table itself to match your field in your list against the parameter.